# Remove space between figure label and number in caption within a separate floating environment

Tags: floats, captions, newfloat

I created a separate floating environment for my supplementary figures using `\usepackage{newfloat} \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Figure S}]{suppfigure}`.

However, this prints in the figure caption "Figure S 1" with a space between S and the number. 
How can I remove this space only for this floating environment?

(I know about `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{S\arabic{table}}`, however this works globally and since I also have normal `figure` environments this is not possible.)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newfloat} \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Figure S}]{suppfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{suppfigure}
    \centering
    \caption{Test}
\end{suppfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `suppfigure` environment has its own counter.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{newfloat}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Figure}]{suppfigure}
\renewcommand{\thesuppfigure}{S\arabic{suppfigure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{suppfigure}
    \centering
    \caption{Test}
\end{suppfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add some negative horizontal space at the end of the name-attribute, like so:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{newfloat} \DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Figure S\hspace{-.6ex}}]{suppfigure}

\begin{document}
\begin{suppfigure}
    \centering
    \caption{Test}
\end{suppfigure}

\end{document}
```

You can fine tune the space to your liking.

[image]